# Matlab: how to run a For loop with multiple outputs?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, output, linear-regression

So my question refers to the regress() function in matlab. [Click here for the Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html)

If I want to run multiple regressions using this function and output both the coefficients and the confidence intervals, what's the best way to do this in a For loop?

Matlab's own syntax for this is [b,bint] = regress(y,X). But when I try to implement this in a for loop it tells me that the dimension mismatch. My code is the following:

```
for i=1:6
[a, b]=regress(Dataset(:,i),capm_factors);
capm_coefs(i,:)=a;
capm_ci(i,:)=b;
end
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regress` outputs a **column vector** of coefficients that minimize the least squared error between your input data (`capm_factors`) and your predicted values (`Dataset(:,i)`).  However, in your `for` loop, you are assuming that `a` and `b` are **row vectors**.

Also, the first output of `regress` is the solution to your system, but the second output contains a **matrix** of confidence values where the first column denotes the lower end of the confidence interval for each variable and the second column denotes the upper end of the confidence interval.

Specifically, your input `capm_factors` should be a `M x N` matrix where `M` is the total number of input samples and `N` is the total number of features.  In your code, `a` would thus give you a `N x 1` vector and `b` would give you a `N x 2` matrix.

If you'd like use a loop, make sure `capm_coefs` is a `N x l` matrix where `l` is the total number of times you want to loop and `capm_ci` should either be a `N x 2 x l` 3D matrix or perhaps a `l` element cell array.  Either way is acceptable.... but I'll show you how to do both.

Something like this comes to mind:

## Confidences as a 3D matrix

```
l = 6; %// Define # of trials
[M,N] = size(capm_factors); %// Get dimensions of data
capm_coefs = zeros(N, l);
capm_ci = zeros(N, 2, l);

for ii = 1 : l
    [a,b] = regress(Dataset(:,i), capm_factors);
    capm_coefs(:,ii) = a;
    capm_ci(:,:,ii) = b;
end
```

You'd then access the coefficients for a trial via `capm_coefs(:,ii)` where `ii` is the iteration you want.  Similarly, the confidence matrix can be accessed via `capm_ci(:,:,ii)`

## Confidences as a cell array

```
l = 6; %// Define # of trials
[M,N] = size(capm_factors); %// Get dimensions of data
capm_coefs = zeros(N, l);
capm_ci = cell(l); %// Cell array declaration

for ii = 1 : l
    [a,b] = regress(Dataset(:,i), capm_factors);
    capm_coefs(:,ii) = a;
    capm_ci{ii} = b; %// Assign confidences to cell array
end
```

Like above, you'd access the coefficients for a trial via `capm_coefs(:,ii)` where `ii` is the iteration you want.  However, the confidence matrix can be accessed via `capm_ci{ii}` as we are now dealing with cell arrays.